# OAuth2: How to send "deny" request to OAuth2 server?

Tags: oauth-2.0

When a user needs to approve a request to authenticate using OAuth2, they are typically given "Approve" and "Cancel" buttons.

What should I send when a users clicks "Cancel" ?

**As a developer, what do I send to the OAuth server to make it deny the request when a user clicks "Cancel" ?**

I tried using a `grant` type of "deny", but that didn't work. I know what to send to get the approval, but can't seem to see what I should send to get the OAuth server to respond with to the `redirect_uri` with an error for the case when a user cancels.

I've reviewed the spec and this nice [OAuth2 Simplified article](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified), but haven't been able to see it.

---

NOTE: I don't see this explicitly detailed anywhere. Is it assumed that my app is supposed to manage this itself? For example, instead of posting to the OAuth2 server in this case, my app just posts to it's own `redirect_uri` instead?

```
{redirect-url}?error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+clicked+deny
```

If so, this seems a little strange, as all implementing clients would have to do this work to construct the url with the error code and reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is part of the standard from what I can see. I think it's left to each OAuth2 service implementor to determine how they want to do it.

For example, [oauth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) is a well used OAuth2 library used by the super popular [Passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) node module, and does it like so:

NOTE: These links may point to old versions of the code. They're canonicalized links to ensure they point to the right place in the code:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/blob/c59aefd14b0fb98f97e3419b8d611c0fb4255c69/lib/middleware/decision.js#L46

https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/blob/c59aefd14b0fb98f97e3419b8d611c0fb4255c69/test/middleware/decision.test.js#L75-L83

Answer (score 8):

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1

> If the resource owner denies the access request or if the request fails for reasons other than a missing or invalid redirection URI, the authorization server informs the client by adding the following parameters to the query component of the redirection URI using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format

Example:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://client.example.com/cb?error=access_denied&state=xyz
```

To redirect in PHP:

```
<?php
http_redirect("https://client.example.com/cb", array("error" => "access_denied", "state" => "xyz", "error_description" => "The user clicked deny"), true, HTTP_REDIRECT_FOUND);
?>
```

Comment: hey... thanks for the feedback... I'm trying to find out how to get the host to respond with a fail to the callback url. I know that's how it typically responds is with a redirect, but I want to know how to make it do that for the cancel case. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with an example to redirect in PHP

Comment: hey... thanks again... The PHP you've written would be inside the OAuth server, correct? That part I understand. What I'm trying to find out is if there's a standard way for a client to *request* the deny operation, e.g. something like `http://anyOAuth2Server/authorize?grant=deny`. I can't seem to see what the "Deny" button is doing anywhere, in any examples. Thanks!

Comment: If the resource owner denied access, there is nothing to to. The OAuth2 server do not issue anything in this case

Comment: Is it acceptable to redirect the client to another page after the client is redirected with the redirected URI? For example, say the client clicks the “Cancel” button and the authorization server redirects him/her to: https://client.example.com/cb?error=access_denied&state=xyz. After that, I’d like my application to redirect the user to another page in my app. Is this allowed? I don’t see in RFC 6749 that I’m not allowed to do this which is why I’m asking.

Comment: AFAIK there is no restriction.